# How can I access the sqlite3 database file in production with electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, electron, create-react-app

I have a **electron** app, and I use it together with the `create-electron-app`.

My electron main process file resides in the **public** folder, and so does my **sqlite3 database**.

When I reference the database in development it works as expected because I can access the path:
`F:\www\project-name\public\api\db\demodb01`

But in production the path does not exist (hidden behind **app.asar** I'd say):
`C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\project-name\resources\app.asar\build\api\db\demodb01`

How can I target the database file in production?

Comment: We would need to see how your project is setup i.e package.json and folder structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When storing files in your application you should use [app.getPath('userData')](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname) to store them outside of your applications scope, which keeps them persisted.

[nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) is a common choice for Electron applications since it's a lightweight database written in JavaScript. If you haven't checked it out, I recommend you to do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've had the same idea of storing the database somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, that's your only solution :)

Answer (score -1):

You have one another solution. Please follow the below steps:

1. First Install [electron-is-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-is-dev)
2. Add these codes inside your main.js file:
   [main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IqYu.jpg)
3. Now in package.json make the following marked changes:
   [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unzbS.jpg)

Thank you.